# Objective-C++ Resize Instance Vector Not Working

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, vector

I have an iOS OpenCV wrapper in Objective-C++ that looks like this:

```cpp
// CVImage.mm

@interface CVImage()
@property std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
@end

@implementation CVImage

...

- (void) findContours
{
  // Find and store contours with cv::findContours
}

// Resize method
- (void) resizeTo:(NSInteger)count
{
  // Stuff that ensures count is less than self.contours.size()

  ...

  self.contours.resize(count);
}

...

@end
```

But the `contours` vector does not resize. They draw to the screen just fine, but if I try to resize or sort it, the code throws an error.

Performing a resize on a local test `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>` variable works, but not my instance member variable.

Am I initializing it wrong in my `CVImage()` category? Or is OpenCV doing something weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. I guess I was initializing it poorly. You have to make sure that `contours` is a pointer (i.e. `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> *`).

Update all the references to match and it works as it should.